# Use cases for when not to use redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I was always wondering if I should use redux store all the time even when it's not really necessary.

For example:

1. I have form with select field that has some options I fetch from API. Let's imagine that form is for adding new car listing and select options are car models. Should I directly call API from component and display options or should I create store `CarModels` or something like that and store results from API there and then map those values to state in component?
2. I have "Favorites" feature, when you click heart next to some item (let's say a car), do I need to go through dispatching all events `FAVORITE_CAR_REQUEST`, `FAVORITE_CAR_SUCCESS` etc... or is it good enough to just call API directly from component (using some kind of api-service of course).
3. It's related to question above. If I have screen where I show favorites, I should then probably have store and connect everything with actual favorite action so I update the list. On new favorite, API will return favorited item, should I push that one in list of favorites already in store or should I just load again latest list when user opens up the favorites screen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can write stateful components but it would be harder to share state, you could lift shared state to a higher component in the tree and use conttext to prevent prop drilling but then it would still be harder to re purpose the component with other logic (reducer/actions). Your question is mostly opinionated so will likely be closed. I almost never write stateful components except for prototype apps or proof of concept and found that in projects that have them they were usually badly written and hard to re use or refactor.

Comment: @HMR Thanks. I was mostly asking for somethings that I don't need further down in the app (like accessing logged in user). "I almost never write stateful components except for prototype apps or proof of concept", how do you write components where forms are presented?

Comment: Form values go into redux, if I want to optimistically update then the user has an option to continue with the application after clicking an update while at the same time have the opportunity to retry and re open the form if it failed. If that info was in state then the info would be gone when component unmounts. Mixing stateful with stateless components usually doesn't make it any easier (testing, debugging, code re use and refactoring) but that's just my opinion, someone else may have a blast using stateful components.

Comment: Thanks for answer @HMR. I never tried storing form values in redux/using redux-form as I read that wasn't most ideal solution but I'll try it in my next project. For now I got answers I needed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a perfectly valid question. What I feel like you're trying to ask is if you could/should mix react state and the redux store. The answer is sure! Just think about where you need to use that part of state before deciding where to store it. If you need a part of the state in multiple components, it probably makes sense to use Redux. If you only need state locally, perhaps to set form validation errors, maybe use react's state management if you feel like it. React and redux are both meant to be flexible, so as long as you're consistent in when you use the redux store and react state you should be good.

I found this article that also explains this pretty well: https://blog.jakoblind.no/is-using-a-mix-of-redux-state-and-react-local-component-state-ok/

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use redux when the state has to be accessed globally / complex logic that i want to be logged properly